# Ember How can i render a child route into his parent?

Tags: ember.js, model, routes

I'm new with Ember and trying to render the content into the `category` template. So, if I clicked on the category, it will show me details and list content in the category template. I have tested something, but it didn't work. I have searched for this problem, but I can't solve it. I hope you can help me.

best regards

app.js

```
TableNotices.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('tableNotices', { path: '/' }, function(){
      this.resource('category', {path: ':id'}, function(){
          this.route('contents');
          this.resource('content', {path: '/content/:id'});
      });
  });
});

TableNotices.ContentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return  this.modelFor('category').get('contents');
    }
});

TableNotices.Content = DS.Model.extend({
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  contentType: DS.attr('string'),
  orderPos: DS.attr('number'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category')
});

TableNotices.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  parent: DS.attr('number'),
  picture: DS.attr('string'),
  contents: DS.hasMany('content', {async:true})
});
```

index.html:

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category">
       {{name}}  
       {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contents">
       foobar
    </script>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cuvutuyube/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Can you throw this up on jsbin? It will make it easier for everyone to help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for correcting my post. I added a jsbin scribble

Answer (score 0):

In the route you can specify how to [render the templates](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) with `renderTemplate`.

```
TableNotices.ContentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return  this.modelFor('category').get('contents');
  }
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('contents', {   // the template to render
      into: 'category',                // the template to render into
      outlet: 'category',              // the name of the outlet in that template
      controller: 'contents'        // the controller to use for the template
   });
 }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category">
   {{name}}  
   {{outlet "contents"}}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, sry i`m stupid. I read it and implement your code. But it didn`t work. If i click on the categorys link, it will show only the properties of the category, but not the content. Is there any other misstake, that i don`t see? http://jsbin.com/liqelurefo/1/

Comment: You don't have the jsbin setup right. Start with a working jsbin. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Although Aaron Renoir's answer will work, the best way to think of this is that because your routes are nested, your templates need to be nested as well. Ember will render each of the nested templates into the parent template when these nested routes are activated. This gives you a nice way to delegate different parts of your page to various templates which helps to keep the content organized.

Each of your "parent" templates will need an {{outlet}} for the child templates to be rendered into.